# Path notification for changes to an object within an array?

Tags: polymer-1.0

We have a large model object that is owned and managed outside of polymer.  We want to expose this model to polymer elements through a proxy element that exposes computed parts of it.

For example, the model may have:

```
{
    blocks: {
       ...
       properties: [
         { ... },  // prop0
         { ... },  // prop1
       ]
    },
}
```

We are using recursive object observers and array observers to monitor changes to the model and notify polymer appropriately (either using `.notifyPath(path, ...)` for object changes and `._notifySplice(...)` for array changes).  However, there doesn't seem to be a good way for us to notify of changes to an object within an array, e.g. `prop0` changed in the example above.

Is there?  What should the path be?

Comment: From the Docs for Polymer 1.0: "The path syntax doesn’t support array-style accessors (such as users[0].name). However, you can include indexes directly in the path (users.0.name)." - Not sure if this was what you were after. :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example using binding to show an updated Polymer property nested inside an object and array:

code:

```
<div>
    <h1>[[blocks.properties[0]]]</h1>
    <p>this updated property should read: Apple</p>
</div>
```

script:

```
Polymer({
  is: "my-page",

  properties: {
    blocks: {
      type: Object,
      value: { properties : ["acorn","banana","carrot"] },
      notify: true
    },
  },

  attached: function() {
    console.log("update");
    this.set('blocks.properties[0]', "Apple");
  },
```

If you need to do array functions you should also use `this.push(path, value)` or `this.splice(path, value)` to notify changes.